# Twillio enable listener to press * to ask to speak during conference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I would like to enable the listener to press * key to ask for unmuting during a conference call, with the moderator able to unmute him/her from a console.

I have a controller with the following :

```
def conference_connect
    @room_name = flash[:room_name]
    @room_id = flash[:event_id]
case params['Digits']
      when "1" # listener
        @muted = "true"
      when "3" # moderator
        @moderator = "true"
    end

    response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
    response.say(voice: 'alice', language: 'en-US', message: 'You are in, press * at anytime to ask a question')
    dial = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new(hangupOnStar: true)
    dial.conference(@room_name,
                    wait_url: "http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?xxxxxxx&",
                    muted: @muted || "false",
                    start_conference_on_enter: @moderator || "false",
                    end_conference_on_exit: @moderator || "false",
                    )

    gather = Twilio::TwiML::Gather.new(action: '/redirectIntoConference?name= ' + @room_name, digits: 1)


    response.append(dial)
  end
```

I have the following error :

```
No template found for TwilioController#conference_connect, rendering head :no_content
```

I would like to send a message to the moderator (or update some params) to notify him that a listener has a question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a couple of issues here. Firstly, your error is because you are not returning the TwiML you built in your controller action and Rails is looking for a template instead.

At the end of the action call `render` like this:

```
  response.append(dial)
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

As for requesting to speak on `*` you are halfway there. Firstly, the `<Gather>` is not going to help you, so get rid of the line:

```
gather = Twilio::TwiML::Gather.new(action: '/redirectIntoConference?name= ' + @room_name, digits: 1)
```

Instead, you have `hangupOnStar` set to true in your `<Dial>` this will disconnect the user from the conference (which sounds bad, but is what you want for this). You just need to setup what happens to the user after they hangup.

In this case, you want to make the request to the moderator and then have them rejoin the conference. You do this with an [`action` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) on the `<Dial>` that points to a URL that will be requested when the caller leaves the conference.

Within this action you need to somehow alert your moderator (I'm not sure how you're planning that) and then return TwiML to enter the caller back into the conference. Don't forget to set the conference up in the same way, with `hangupOnStar` and an `action`.

Ulitmately your action should look a bit like this:

```
def conference_connect
  @room_name = flash[:room_name]
  @room_id = flash[:event_id]
  case params['Digits']
  when "1" # listener
    @muted = "true"
  when "3" # moderator
    @moderator = "true"
  end

  response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
  response.say(voice: 'alice', language: 'en-US', message: 'You are in, press * at anytime to ask a question')
  dial = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new(hangupOnStar: true, action: '/redirectIntoConference?name= ' + @room_name)
  dial.conference(@room_name,
                  wait_url: "http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?xxxxxxx&",
                  muted: @muted || "false",
                  start_conference_on_enter: @moderator || "false",
                  end_conference_on_exit: @moderator || "false",
                  )    
  response.append(dial)
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi Philnash, I just tried and I get an application error without any update in my console. I do not know which parameters/line failed.

Comment: If you get the message saying application error, then you should see a message in the Twilio debugger: https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger

Comment: Ok, I see Invalid URL format (Error 11100). I kept the url as "  dial = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new(hangupOnStar: true, action: '/redirectIntoConference?name= ' + @room_name)" that seem to be an incorrect URL. @room_name string does display properly in the Request inspector tho

Comment: May I ask how should a correct url look like (like an example) please

Comment: You may need to URL escape the room name (`action: "/redirectIntoConference?name=#{CGI.escape(@room_name)}"`). Also, I thought TwiML was fine with a relative URL, but you might try sending the full absolute URL too.

Comment: Hi Philnash, sorry for the absence, I was working on other part of the project. So i tried the     dial = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new(hangupOnStar: true, action: "/conference/redirectIntoConference?name=#{CGI.escape(@room_name)}")
, and I find myself with another error saying the redirectIntoConference does not exist. How should I build it pls ? also how do I make sure that the users returns into the call muted? I appreciate your help, this is the last part of this project. Thank you

Comment: I assumed you had implemented the `redirectIntoConference` path as it was in your question. You need to return [`<Conference>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) to drop your user back into the conference for this. You can make the user muted by including the `muted="true"` attribute.

Comment: yes i did create the route. so how do I "return <Conference> TwiML" please ?

Comment: I have just created a ticket with the support at Twilio. I think I am very close, all I need is a line of code probably, and I have no clue how to do it. Thank you for your help @Philnash